# Cannot install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded visual studio 2017 15.7.6 with these following workloads

1. .Net desktop development.
2. ASP.NET and web development.
3. Mobile development with .Net

After installing everything I get this warning "setup complete with warning" and then i clicked "View problem". The problem then shows "Cannot install Microsoft.Visualstudio.Community.Msi".
This is the full error log,

> Something went wrong with the install.
>
> You can troubleshoot the package failures by:
>
> 1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
> 2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
> 3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again
>
> If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.
>
> ================================================================================
>
> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi,version=15.7.27617.1' failed to install.
>       Search URL
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1406
>       Details
>           MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi,version=15.7.27617.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  PIDKEY="NGKBDRWKQFTT82MTRMPKRM6XM"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"  FEEDBACKOPTIN="1" 
>           Return code: 1603
>           Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
>           Message Id: 1406
>           Message Details: Could not write value PrimaryInteropAssemblyName to key \Software\Classes\TypeLib{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}\1.0.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
>       Log
>           C:\Users\MysterHyde\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20200309103712_053_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi.log
>       Impacted workloads
>           .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.7.27625.0)
>       Impacted components
>           .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools,version=15.7.27617.1)
>           .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           .NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.6.27309.0)
>           ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           ASP.NET and web development tools prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.6.27406.0)
>           C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.27205.0)
>           ClickOnce Publishing (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           Cloud tools for web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           Connectivity and publishing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=1.10.50912.1)
>           Data sources and service references (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.6.27406.0)
>           Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26621.2)
>           Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.7.27617.1)
>           Entity Framework 6 tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.6.27406.0)
>           F# language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.7.27604.0)
>           F# language support for web projects (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates,version=15.7.27703.1)
>           IIS Express  (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           JavaScript diagnostics (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,version=15.7.27520.0)
>           Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.6.27323.2)
>           Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
>           Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
>           NuGet package manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.6.27309.0)
>           Razor Language Services (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.RazorExtension,version=15.0.26720.2)
>           SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.7.27625.0)
>           Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.7.27604.0)
>           Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.7.27617.1)
>           Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26606.0)>

I tried downloading other version but i'm still getting the same error. I disabled my antivirus but it also didn't work. Please I need help it frustrating, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Return code: 1603`: first think to try is a reboot and then run the install again (1603 indicates there may be pending installation tasks awaiting a reboot).

Comment: @Richard, so i should restart my computer?

Comment: Yes. (Extra for minimum comment length.)

Comment: @Richard still didn't work i got the same error.

Comment: Separate components have their own installer logs: you'll need to see if you can find a more specific error

Comment: @ so I should download each workload at a time?

Comment: No, go through the specific installer logs. There is a top level one (that you have looked at), and then separate ones for some components one of which may have more specific information.

Comment: @Richard i don't get it, what top level one? Can you elaborate?

Comment: There are multiple log files from when the VS installer is run. You've only looked at one of them.

Comment: @Richard, the log file I look at comes with the error, but where can i find the other log files?

Comment: In the same folder? (The last time I had to diagnose a problem with the VS installer there were a whole load in the same place: try sorting by date to keep them together.)

Comment: Same folder is my recollection, but then I recall they were all in `%TEMP%`.

Answer (score 0):

> I disabled my antivirus but it also didn't work. Please I need help it
> frustrating, what am i doing wrong?

Please try these steps:

**1)** Launch **regedit** as **Administrators**

**2)** Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}\1.0`-->Right click-->`launch Permissions` -> `Advanced`

- Ensure the Owner is SYSTEM
- System and Administrator have Full Control to keys and subkeys.

**Meanwhile**, please check if you have specialized anti-virus, app-blocker, or GPO phased permission software installed that maybe be denying access to this key.

**3)** then do a reboot and after that, try to temporarily disable the anti-virus software and then run VS Installer as administrator to [repair your installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

In addition, if these does not work, please reinstall VS2017(please install the VS2017 15.9 which is the latest VS2017 version) under [this link](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017).

After you uninstall VS2017, please check if you have this: `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`.

- If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param: InstallCleanup.exe -full
- If not, please manually delete the %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer folder

**And** then insatll VS2017 under my link and please remember to run it as admin.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Hello, please I couldn't find `TypeLib{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}` under `classes` in regedit

Comment: You cannot see that key which means you did not have the permission under the current address. So if you can't see the contents of the folder under which step, you give it permission, and then please go down in order.

Comment: How do i give it permission, I don't know where the folder `TypeLib{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}` is, please if you can tell what exactly im to give permission to.

Comment: Please try to right-click on the `Classes`-->launch `Permissions` -> `Advanced` and make sure the current user has permissions. If  Classes folder does not exist, please do the same operation to the upper folder. Besides, as a suggestion, please also check this under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: Hello, please the  current user has permission already, full control access.

Comment: In my further answer, l have missed the `\` under `TypeLib{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}` ,and if you input the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}` or step over by UI in the registry editor and still cannot find it, I think you should reinstall VS2017 with my link and steps under the answer. And as l know, there is no such official download link to `VS2017 15.7.6`. Please try my download link to install  vs2017 15.9.

Comment: I've followed the steps and both systems and administrator don't have full control, only read. But I cant find a way to change it.

Comment: Actually, you should contact with your administrator for the permission to change the key since your company has the  safety mechanisms.

Comment: If you have any other concern further, please feel free to let us know.