# A problem during the installation or adding components to Visual studio 2022: Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, maui, regedit

I am trying to add MAUI environment to my existing installation of Visual studio 2022, however the installation using visual studio installer fails. This is the error I get in the logs:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=17.6.33606.225' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1407
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=17.6.33606.225\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  PIDKEY="NGKBDRWKQFTT82MTRMPKRM6XM"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"  FEEDBACKOPTIN="1" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
        Message Id: 1407
```

I have tried to install the problematic MSI package manually from the following path that I got from the logs `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi,version=17.6.33606.225\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi.msi` but it keeps failing.

Further searching on the internet, I came across [someone proposing a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1096342/visual-studio-2022-installation-error) that might work , they say I should edit a registry key, but navigating to that key through regedit makes regedit freeze, stop responding and crashing. So I came to the conclusion that the MSI package needs access to that key but is not able to use it for whatever reason and I cannot figure out why..

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599565/cannot-install-microsoft-visualstudio-community-msi)

Just needed to change something, the owner of the key to edit should be an Administrator account and not SYSTEM because apparently, windows prevents editing permissions for a SYSTEM owned key

Comment: You could try whether repair can solve this problem, and if possible, please share detailed steps. :)